AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'read'
I wanted to do a migration, but I got an error
My python version in the virturalenv is Python 3.12.3
I haven't found a single appropriate response to stackoverflow yet.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anton/Documents/project2/backend/my_backend/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/anton/Documents/project2/backend/my_backend/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/anton/Documents/project2/backend/pr2_venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/anton/Documents/project2/backend/pr2_venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/anton/Documents/project2/backend/pr2_venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 81, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/anton/Documents/project2/backend/pr2_venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 68, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/anton/Documents/project2/backend/pr2_venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 166, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/anton/Documents/project2/backend/my_backend/my_backend/settings.py", line 12, in <module>
    environ.Env.read_env(BASE_DIR / '.env')
  File "/home/anton/Documents/project2/backend/pr2_venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/environ/environ.py", line 646, in read_env
    content = f.read()
              ^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'read'

I had the same error when I reconnected the postgres database and then sqlite3 again.

Convert it to a string first:
environ.Env.read_env(str(BASE_DIR / '.env'))
read_env probably cannot work with Path objects.

thanks this problem solved, but immediately appeared the second one with “ ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘django.contrib.contenttyfrom datetime import timedelta’ ” I also can't find this problem, and I can't find that file in which this typo is also I can't, if you don't spare your time please help me.

@Anton: you apparently wrote some import statements in the env file? That makes not much sense. .env files are not Python files. You can not write arbitrary python, it is just KEY=VAL, that's it.

Yeah, I got SECRET_KEY and DEBUG.
Here they are in settings.py “ SECRET_KEY = env(‘SECRET_KEY’).
DEBUG = env('DEBUG')”

@Anton: not in the settings file, in the .env file, or in some string literal.

in .env SECRET_KEY=django-insecure-3+qcjvwgd8r95x++s85nwz7xa+#^v2hiv7-pft6z)q1k5)gx&w
DEBUG=True

@Anton: perhaps ask a new question with the full traceback.
